# S3 HDFS with No File Owner - AccessControlException

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm currently running a small Hadoop cluster for HDFS and MapReduce, and I'm trying to swap out S3 for local HDFS as per the page here:

[AmazonS3 for HDFS](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3)

The issue I'm running into is that when starting the JobTracker, if metadata (jobtracker.info) already exists, when Hadoop tries to access/overwrite this file, it can't open it because the owner of that file does not match the MapRed owner.  In hadoop-core-1.0.3 ([JobTracker.java](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java.html)), the comparison:

```
FileStatus systemDirStatus = fs.getFileStatus(systemDir);
if (!systemDirStatus.getOwner().equals( getMROwner().getShortUserName())) {
    throw new AccessControlException("The systemdir " + systemDir +
      " is not owned by " + getMROwner().getShortUserName());
}
```

Where `systemDirStatus.getOwner()` returns an empty string (s3 file owner) and `getMROwner().getShortUserName()` returns "*mapred*", though this value can easily be changed to anything other than an empty string by setting the `HADOOP_USER_NAME` environment variable on the JobTracker node.

This issues is a casualty of S3 not maintaining "File Owners", and Hadoop's NativeS3Filesystem and Jets3t do nothing to compensate for this fact.

Is there is a way around this without patching Hadoop?  I figure there must be some way of accomplishing this, seeing as EMR is S3 backed.  Note that we do not yet want to move to EMR and would like to continue running MapReduce on our own EC2 cluster while using S3 for HDFS.

Thank You in Advance!

Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after further research, I've stumbled upon the solution to my problem:

The issue described above, where S3 does not maintain file permissions/owners, manifests itself in two different places while attempting to use Hadoop JobTrakcers backed by S3 as HDFS:

1. During JobTrakcer restart, when a jobtracker.conf file already exists.
2. While transitioning to the second task of a job when the JobTrakcer attempts to obtain information from the Staging directory in HDFS.

The former of these issues never manifests in Elastic MapReduce, because "JobTrackers" are only ever started once and are destroyed upon job completion.  The second, however, can fall victim to a check in the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles` class, depending on which version of Hadoop you are using.

In most CDH3 distros (I only checked cdh3u3, cdh3u4, and cdh3u5), file owner and permissions are checked in two separate statements to add more detailed logging (snippet from cdh3u5 - [JobSubmissionFiles.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u5/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobSubmissionFiles.java?av=f)):

```
FileStatus fsStatus = fs.getFileStatus(stagingArea);
  String owner = fsStatus.getOwner();
  if (!(owner.equals(currentUser) || owner.equals(realUser))) {
     throw new IOException("The ownership on the staging directory " +
                  stagingArea + " is not as expected. " + 
                  "It is owned by " + owner + ". The directory must " +
                  "be owned by the submitter " + currentUser + " or " +
                  "by " + realUser);
  }
  if (!fsStatus.getPermission().equals(JOB_DIR_PERMISSION)) {
    LOG.info("Permissions on staging directory " + stagingArea + " are " +
      "incorrect: " + fsStatus.getPermission() + ". Fixing permissions " +
      "to correct value " + JOB_DIR_PERMISSION);
    fs.setPermission(stagingArea, JOB_DIR_PERMISSION);
  }
```

Notice that if `String owner` has a null or empty string value, it will never match `currentUser` or `realUser`, which are pulled from the machine that is running the job.

In older AND more recent versions of hadoop, including Apache 0.20.2, 1.0.x, and 2.0.x, as well as CDH4, this check is combined into a single statement, allowing the empty owner to roll over into Default Permissions" (Snippet from Apache Hadoop 1.0.3 - [JobSubmissionFiles.java](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobSubmissionFiles.java.html)):

```
FileStatus fsStatus = fs.getFileStatus(stagingArea);
  String owner = fsStatus.getOwner();
  if (!(owner.equals(currentUser) || owner.equals(realUser)) || 
      !fsStatus.getPermission().equals(JOB_DIR_PERMISSION)) {
     throw new IOException("The ownership/permissions on the staging " +
                  "directory " + stagingArea + " is not as expected. " + 
                  "It is owned by " + owner + " and permissions are "+ 
                  fsStatus.getPermission() + ". The directory must " +
                  "be owned by the submitter " + currentUser + " or " +
                  "by " + realUser + " and permissions must be rwx------");
  }
```

Long story short, switching to a version of Hadoop with the collapsed comparison instead of the expanded comparison fixed my S3 woes.