# Not able to run MapReduce second time onwards in EC2 with S3 for storage

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mapreduce

I have setup Single Node hadoop in Amazon EC2 instance. Following [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) and [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) I can run the example program for the first time. But to get it running it second time, I have to delete all the directories and files in S3 and local tmp directories after stopping issuing stop-all.sh . I am only running mapred (tasktracker and jobtracker). Attempting to re-run the example for second time onwards I get the error message.

```
        hduser@ip-10-252-196-143:~$ hadoop jar ./hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar  wordcount input output2
13/09/20 09:43:06 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:java.io.IOException: The ownership on the staging directory s3://vikesh-hadoop-bucket/home/hduser/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser/.staging is not as expected. It is owned by . The directory must be owned by the submitter hduser or by hduser
java.io.IOException: The ownership on the staging directory s3://vikesh-hadoop-bucket/home/hduser/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser/.staging is not as expected. It is owned by . The directory must be owned by the submitter hduser or by hduser
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755424/s3-hdfs-with-no-file-owner-accesscontrolexception) is related, but is using Cloudera's distribution I believe.

Why is this happening and what can I do to solve this ? I am using hadoop-1.2.1 with OpenJDK 7 on a 64 bit VM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same problem. We simply delete the s3://{bucket-name}/home/{user}/tmp/mapred/staging/{user}/.staging between each MapReduce... But if someone has a better solution...

Comment: I don't think so also, but at this point I am not sure a better solution is available...

Comment: But this is not a proper solution. I am facing the same problem in Apache-Tez. Look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421957/tez-job-fails-when-submitting-by-different-user

Comment: Does anybody have more information on this issue?  The workaround of deleting the directories each time a job is run is not an acceptable fix for our use case.