# Tez job fails when submitting by different user

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

Configured Hadoop-2.6.0 HA cluster with Kerberos security. When submitting example job using tez-example-0.6.0.jar in `yarn-tez` framework from different user, getting the below exception

**Exception**

```
java.io.IOException: The ownership on the staging directory hdfs://clustername/tmp/staging is not as expected. It is owned by Kumar. The directory must be owned by the submitter TestUser or by TestUser
```

The directory has full permission but still getting the above exception. But when submitting a job using mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar in `yarn-tez` framework then the job completed successfully.

**Command**

```
yarn jar C:\Tez\tez-examples-0.6.0.jar orderedwordcount -Dmapreduce.framework.name=yarn-tez  /user/Kumar/names /user/Kumar/names1
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Set the following in your tez-site.xml:

```
<property>
   <name>tez.staging-dir</name>
   <value>/tmp/${user.name}/tez/staging/</value>
</property>
```

The current staging directory seems to be configured to use /clustername/tmp/staging/ which ends up using the same path for multiple users causing permission conflicts.

If you use /clustername/tmp as the prefix, please be sure to pre-create the tmp dir and have 777 permissions on it.